# LWP::UserAgent to post XML to secure server... certificate issue

Tags: xml, perl, ssl, lwp-useragent

I'm using LWP::UserAgent to do a POST of XML data to a remote server.  The remote URL is https, and they sent me a .crt file to install on my server.

When I try to connect to their server, I get the following message:

> An Error Occurred
>
> 500 Can't connect to previewtest.clverify.com:443 (certificate verify
>   failed) 500 Can't connect to previewtest.clverify.com:443 (certificate
>   verify failed) Content-Type: text/plain Client-Date: Wed, 25 Jan 2012
>   05:11:24 GMT Client-Warning: Internal response Can't connect to
>   previewtest.clverify.com:443 (certificate verify failed)
>   LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown
>   errorerror:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed at
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.

How do I appropriately reference the SSL Certificate on my server and send it to theirs?

Here is the code:

```
sub ConsumerInfo {
my $cid = shift;

my $response = undef;
my $sendXML = &Create_ConsumerInfo_Request($cid);
if ($sendXML) {
    &DoXMLUpload($sendXML);

    my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'perl post');
    $browser->credentials('sumURL:443','sumRealm','sumUserID'=>'sumPassword');
    $response = $browser->request(POST 'sumFullURL',
        Content_Type => 'text/xml',
        Content => $sendXML);
    print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
    print $response->error_as_HTML unless $response->is_success;
    print $response->as_string;
} else {
    &ErrorMsg("No XML Code Was Found.");
    exit;   
}
# ===============================================================
# Need to insert parser in here to convert this into an array.
# ===============================================================
return $response;
}
```

Now... let's say that the certs that were sent to me are located at /usr/bin/some_dir/DigiCertCA.crt.

How do I set this to check my certs when the server is called?

Comment: As additional info, the third-party vendor we are connecting to sent me 2 .crt files:   DigiCertCA.crt and TrustedRoot.crt.  I installed them on my server with CPanel.

Comment: Some sample Perl code would be helpful to us, to help you.

Comment: Sorry... just edited the question, and posted some code.

Comment: http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2011/07/now-you-need-lwpprotocolhttps.html - this blog explains the use of "ssl_opts" that LWP offers.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd try changing the `my $browser` line to:

```
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new(
  agent => 'perl post',
  ssl_opts => {
    verify_hostname => 1,
    SSL_ca_path => '/usr/bin/some_dir',
  },
);
```

Comment: OK... made that change, to no effect.  Here is the code being run currently:

<code>my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'perl post',
  ssl_opts => {
      verify_hostname => 1,
      SSL_ca_path => '/home/site/ssl/certs/',
    },);
 $browser->credentials('netaddr:port','realm','username'=>'password');
 $response = $browser->request(POST 'fullURL',
  Content_Type => 'text/xml',
  Content => $sendXML);
}</code>